# JWPLAYER Video cannot show on facebook timeline, but can show on wall & news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, jwplayer

I am developing a function to share a video with embedded JWPlayer on facebook.
I can watch the video on the wall and news feed after post on facebook, but not on facebook personal timeline page.

Please help me to fix why I cannot watch the jwplayer video on the fb timeline page.

The share link.
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://{domain}/english/specialprogramme.html

- domain = 113.28.88.71

The website link:
http://{domain}/english/specialprogramme.html

- domain = 113.28.88.71

Comment: This is something that Facebook has changed on their end it seems. Nothing has changed on the JW Player end, but it looks like embeds that used to work are now no longer working.